# Tips for dexterously handling bike lights with winter gloves

Tags: winter, technique, lighting, damage

I've got some battery-powered LED lights which are mounted using the typical "click-in" bike mounts somewhat like the one pictured below:
[image: "Click-in" bike light mount]

Unfortunately, I've got the fine motor skill of an elephant. This in combination with wearing thick winter gloves, being tired during/after riding and everything being wet and slippery means that I drop bike lights *a lot*. Somehow, I think that I might not be the only person to have these struggles in winter, so **what can I do to attach/detach/carry bike lights in winter without dropping them?** — I can't leave them on because they will get stolen. The temperatures are often below -10°C, which means that taking my gloves off even for a few seconds is extremely painful and they go numb... and then my hands are even more useless than before.

Comment: Probably a silly question - is it so cold that you can't remove the gloves while you fit the lights?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you putting them on while riding? If not, either put them on and leave them on, or don't use gloves when doing it.

Comment: @OllyHodgson, if I remove my gloves, my hands are even more useless because they start to hurt and go numb within a few seconds.

Comment: @andy256, do you live somewhere where no one ever steals anything?

Comment: @errantlinguist Right, so it's really *cold*. In that case I can only suggest shopping around for lights with big, easy to use clamps? Perhaps put some grip-tape around the body of the lamp to make it harder to drop?

Comment: Wear polypro glove liners.  They're not as easy to find as they were 20 years ago, but I still see them on the web.

Comment: I'm confused by the concept of "So cold that I can't even take gloves off even for a few seconds but warm enough to engage in moderate outdoor physical exercise."

Comment: @DavidRicherby, does cycling not keep you warm? However, does it keep your *fingers* warm?-- sadly not.

Comment: @errantlinguist Cycling requires breathing much more than one's resting rate. In my fairly limited experience of being outdoors in temperatures of, say, -10C, breathing hard is uncomfortable. On the other hand, my experience of retrieving items from domestic chest freezers (which are at about -18C) is that my hands certainly don't go numb in just a few seconds at those temperatures and, indeed, they don't go numb in the time it takes me to carry the frozen whatever across the kitchen. Hands going numb faster than the time taken to put on bike lights sounds like extreme cold or high windchill.

Comment: @errantlinguist And you wear the gloves _while cycling_ to keep your hands warm. What we can't understand is why you can't take them off briefly to put your lights on the bike _before you cycle_.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, for whatever reason, when I'm done riding for 45 min. at -5 to -10, taking off my gloves makes my hands hurt way more than they already do; I can't compare my pain/numbness to others as experience is inherently subjective, but I can at least say for myself that the only part of me which suffers when cycling are my hands.

Comment: You might be able to jury rig some setup using bolts, zip ties, super glue, etc that would make it hard to remove without tools. Remember that any thief is probably also in gloves! If you don't mind loosing the click-in functionality, I could see super gluing the upper part and replacing the QR with a nut/bolt of some kind.

Comment: I'm not saying the OP suffers from a specific condition but[Raynaud's syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raynaud_syndrome) can make extremities very sensitive to the cold (to the extent that a friend of mine can be seen in spring/autumn in short sleeves and ski gloves).

Comment: @ChrisH, I was actually considering starting yet another question at this exact moment, this time titled "Why are my hands so ridiculously cold?"... but then all I'd get are recommendations to go to doctors, who seem to always take my money and time and do absolutely nothing.

Comment: More cycling-specific and less medical idea: glove seams letting in a cold wind especially when you go quickly.  Cheap ski gloves do this badly.

Comment: @ChrisH, yes, I do notice a difference at least re. wind: If it's very windy/wet outside, I usually have synthetic "windbreaking" gloves with a cotton glove underneath; If it's just cold without being wet or windy, I can wear a heavy woolen+Thinsulate glove... my hands feel colder at 5C with the former than at -5C with the latter...

Comment: @DanielRHicks Ditto.  But you probably don't need to bother going that far.  You can get "stretchy" (polyester/lycra blend or something) gloves here in the dollar store that work fine this way -- fit tight, very thin, easy to wear under a bulkier pair, washable, I just got 2 pairs for $3.  Another option are certain kinds of work gloves intended for fine finger work; you can find these cheap in hardware stores, and they usually have the added biking bonus of padded palms.

Comment: @errantlinguist OK, so the actual problem is that, after cycling, your hands are so cold that you find it difficult to take your lights off your bike? So isn't the solution to wear better gloves so your hands are warm when you arrive and you can take a glove off to remove your lights?

Comment: @goldilocks - I bought some similar sounding gloves at a hardware store last winter.  They're thicker than the polypro gloves and not as warm.

Comment: Oh for sure they are not as good -- but they are most likely sufficient.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, the problem is that I have never found gloves which actually keep my hands "warm" without [being as dexterous as astronauts' gloves](https://www.outdoorresearch.com/en/alti-gloves.html) (I actually have these gloves and they are so warm you can't wear them above about -10)... and once I take my hands out of them in order to do something, they get cold anyway. Combined with being tired and in a rush and with everything around being wet and slippery, bike lights don't last long.

Comment: I read through the conversation and now I'm just wondering how does it stay wet at -10C.

Comment: Poagies were invented because gloves in freezing temperatures are always a trade off.  If they keep your hands warm, you won't have any dexterity.  Anyone regularly riding in freezing or lower temperatures should just give up on gloves, you will never find a good enough setup.  Your hands will always be too cold, or your controls will be difficult to use.

Comment: @ojs, temperature rarely stays exactly at a single given even integer value, does it?

Comment: No, but it's quite rare for it to change by 10 degrees during a single ride.

Comment: I don't think it's been said, but don't start a ride with cold hands or cold gloves.  In winter I keep my bike gloves in the airing cupboard, and leave the house gloved up - because on top of the cold I need to handle metal doors and locks.  If it's really chilly I'll deliberately warm my hands before gloving up and going out.

Comment: @ojs I'm not sure how it's possible to define a climate here unambiguously in natural language: Some days it's -5.2. Some days it's -12.3. Some days it's +5.4522. Some days the snow melts. Some days it rains and mixes with the snow+mud+slush. Some days it freezes again. Some days it snows over the frozen mud+slush. Not every place is a winter wonderland where temperature stays exactly at one value, and I thought that with global warming it would become even less common, or am I wrong? Am I the only human being on this site who lives in this sort of climate?

Comment: **Meta-question:** There are tons of useful tips here (which I've accordingly upvoted) but no One Answer which I've tried (yet) and fixes my problem; How do I choose which to accept, if any?

Comment: @errantlinguist no, you are not the only one with that kind of climate. The simple solution is to use different gloves for different weather. I kind of expected you had figured it out since you had one exact temperature in the question.

Comment: @ojs, my question wasn't directly about gloves (see e.g. [this great answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44154/8685)) despite that the conversation seems to have gone that way... that's why I threw in the "tired, cold, wet and clumsy" bit. **I drop lights no matter what I wear on my hands, and being cold and wet makes it even worse.** Oh well.

Comment: @ojs Warm gloves that reduce your ability to shift and/or brake properly are hardly a "completely fine solution".  I suspect your experience with cold weather riding is limited.

Comment: @SuspendedUser your suspicion is completely wrong. If we go down this track, I might as well suspect that you have never ridden a bike or worn gloves.

Comment: @errantlinguist that's a completely different question. To help with hand coordination, practice with baoding balls, try finger exercises for guitar players or even learn to play an instrument.

Comment: @ojs, no, it's not a different question: I wrote "Unfortunately, I've got the fine motor skill of an elephant. This in combination with wearing thick winter gloves, being tired during/after riding and everything being wet and slippery means that I drop bike lights *a lot*". The fact that this prompts most people on SE to go spend lots of money on gloves doesn't mean that I in fact asked for glove-buying advice.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you are looking for an argument. Well, this is the internet, you are in the right place.

Comment: @ojs, while buying something might be a reasonable thing to do, I find it very alienating that most of the answers on this site for time-sensitive problems are not financially feasible for me (at least right now, when I need it). In other words, I can't use most of this advice yet people keep giving it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49855/discussion-on-question-by-errantlinguist-tips-for-dexterously-handling-bike-ligh).

Answer (score 9):

For similar fine tasks, silk inner gloves are ideal. They are very thin but add a noticeable amount of warmth. Their real benefit comes when you remove the outer gloves and have essentially bare hand dexterity with some insulation. Then you just have to get your timing right to minimise the amount of time your outer gloves are off.

Some people use latex or nitrile gloves in a similar way but I find them too sweaty.

Comment: I prefer polypropylene -- much warmer than silk but still quite thin, and they "breathe" very well.  They've gotten harder to find (wool seems to be the rage for some reason) but I still see them when I Google.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, thanks for the tip re. polypropylene: I've got some cheap silk liners which are much better than nothing but still aren't terribly warm.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I haven't tried polypropylene but a quick search finds some that look quitre good, if thicker than the silk ones I've still got somewhere (they're so small rolled up that they hide).

Comment: too thin. They provide basically no warmth, especially if it is snowing, in which case they will get wet instantly.

Comment: The idea is to wear them under wind- and waterproof gloves.

Comment: I have some Helly Hansen ones and they add a bit of warmth, wick the sweat away and slide more easily back in to gloves than bare hands. Well worth looking out for something like this. Try the ski shops not just bike retailers.

Answer (score 6):

To add a bit of perspective to the glove liner/inner gloves answers:

[image]

I stopped spending much money on this kind of thing a long time ago because it isn't really necessary.  If you have the budget and the shopping time, getting the best of everything is of course great (in this case, you probably want two, one backup).  However, I live in Canada and like to cross country ski (and also ride my bike in the winter) and I use this arrangement in -20°C weather on frozen lakes, where there is no where to hide if 30-40 km/h winds spring up, you have hours to go, and you now cannot usefully expose bare hands for any length of time.

- The first picture are cheap (~$2) synthetic stretch gloves that can be found almost anywhere.  The thing to avoid here is anything with too much cotton, since it absorbs sweat and looses its insulation value when wet.  These breath well and even soaked can be rung out and remain better than nothing.  They look like kid size gloves but stretch.
- The second picture is them under another pair of relatively light, non-waterproof, thinsulate gloves, to illustrate they're fine under anything.  The outer layer comes on and off easily.  I can actually pack both layers into a snowmobile mitt, although that is a bit excessive. If you are sweating, having some free play between layers is better.
- The third picture are work gloves, ~$5. These are more windproof but not as snug, so don't fit as well under other things -- but note that you want loose, and not tight, here anyway, because if it all packs too tight it will hamper your circulation.  Those work fine for me under, e.g., water resistant ski gloves that are bulkier than the ones in the center picture. These are also something you could keep warm and dry in a pocket and only take out when you need to work on the bike. The black leather-esque material grips well.

So again, if you have access to a good outdoor store and want to spend $20 on proper inner gloves, you'll have a better product.  Personally, I'd rather have *two* pairs of cheap ones though.  They're light and ball up to egg size, so it is easy to keep the extra pair warm and dry somewhere inside your jacket.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend a set of poagies, which will likely be far warmer than your gloves to start with.  You can throw chemical warmers in them to really make them like an oven.  At that point a very thin set of gloves (like regular summer full fingers) that still offer some protection can be used quite effectively for short bursts outside your poagies.  For one to have immediate problems when removing gloves in the cold, it suggests a circulatory issue, or that your hands were not reasonably warm to start will.  Either way a good set of poagies will put you in a better starting place.
[image: Poagies]
I would also look into the headlamp idea.  The main disadvantage to a headlamp is riding with one while snowing.  The rest of the time they work as well or better than most bike mounted lights and require no extra effort when you leave your bike.  I actually wear my red blinky (as well as sometimes a total of three) attached to the headband of my headlamp and call it my "crown of dorkdom".  It looks dumb, but it can't be missed.  It also means I don't have to mess around with my blinkies in the cold.  When it gets really cold, plastic gets brittle, and dealing with cold plastic as little as possible is the best way to extend it's life.

Comment: +1 but I disagree that a head-mounted lamp "work[s] as well or better than most bike mounted lights." Correctly adjusted bike-mounted lights don't blind every motorist you look at. They don't disappear when you look to the side. They don't confuse the hell out of everyone if you look over your shoulder. They're at a similar height to other vehicle lights, so it's easier for people to judge your distance. I agree that they may be a very good compromise in the situation being addressed, but they also have significant disadvantages.

Comment: Disadvantages and advantages.  Most headlights have a tilt that can be adjusted so you aren't blinding motorists.  Headlamps are more flexible in that you can look with your eyes and have your light not move OR look with your head if you are trying to check areas.  I find this useful in turns where bikelights will not illuminate where you are going (forward in the turn), but a headlamp can.  I also find it useful in situations like street crossings where a motorist is going to make a right on green instead of yielding and I WANT to look and blind them so they stop and yield.

Comment: Pogs made with tanned and cured rabbit fur are the most awesome winter biking gloves.  Treat them with proofide and waterproofing waxes and you'll have dry hands all the way.

Comment: I am pretty sure if I was going to do skins, I'd go caribou.

Comment: @SuspendedUser No, you want them to SEE you so they stop and yield. Seeing is the opposite of being blind. Being blind and in control of a ton of moving machinery is DANGEROUS.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That hasn't been my experience.  People at a stop waiting to turn right who can "see" will often go, despite the fact that they actually haven't looked and don't have the right of way.  People who have just been hit (briefly) with a very bright light will stay put as they try to figure out what is going on; occasionally they'll even put down their cell phones as they try to ascertain what they missed.

Comment: Poagies sound like the best answer to just about any problem, but they look like they will be stolen in about 10 minutes; Is there a way to quickly remove them after biking? If not, then I have exactly the same problem I did with lights, albeit with the poagies.

Comment: They take less than 10 seconds to install or remove.  They have a cinch cord that keeps them on (can be seen dangling on the far left of the picture).  If you had some sort of odd brake or shifting setup it might be a bit tricker, but all my standard setups require on that small bit of time.  I have actually removed/installed them while riding before on races with changing conditions.

Answer (score 4):

First idea is to attach some stiff cord that you will first string over your handlebar or just lamp mounting point. Then you can try as much as you want to put your light on. On drop it will hang on the cord. It has to be not too long.

Second guess is to change lamp type. I had no problem putting torch-like lamp to that kind of handle, but unfortunately torch lamps are not the best option for bicycles:[image]

Third idea is to use Headlamp 
[image]
and taillamp integrated in your helmet.
[image]
 You can prepare it when you're in warm place. I think it should be just an addition to regular lights, but this is kind of solution for you. Note: assure that regulations in your area allows you to use on-body lamps.

Last idea, in my opinion the best one, but also the most revolutionary - move to hub dynamo powered, permanently mounted lamps.

Comment: Great point wrapping a cord around your handlebars.  That has saved my lights from falling onto the ground while riding many times.

Comment: Clamps with a (much) bigger release trigger than what the OP shows is also an option. I have somthing like https://magshop.lezyne.com/ledlights/cm-handlebar-mount-mega-xl.html and have no problems with it with thick gloves + liner.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can actually take your gloves off for a few seconds at -10. Even at -20, if you are not in the wind. Make sure your hands and gloves are warmed up before (and for that, make sure the rest of your body is properly covered and warm. When you stop right after a ride it should be the case), take off one glove, do what you have to do, put it on again.

It is not pleasurable, it might hurt a bit, but if you really need those fine motor skills, you can do it. Just make sure to put your hand back in the glove before you stop feeling you fingers.

Now, I understand that you would not like to do that everyday, or several times per day. So:

- Store your bike inside (in a garage, for example), if possible. Even if you still need to remove the lights, you can now do it in a warm place
- Use a headlamp, as suggested by krzyski, but use one that mounts on your helmet. More than likely you have a helmet and a face mask that covers your face, and no room to fit a headlamp on your forehead (I know I don't).
- Use a lamp that cannot be stolen easily (screwed on with a special screwdriver). Thieves may think twice about stealing a bike lamp if it involves fine motor skills and special tools
- Use 2 pairs of gloves BUT make sure the liner pair is wind resistant and warm, and have some level of water resistance if it snows. (not a very thin silk glove) You'll get less motor skills, but more that with those big gloves of course.
- Use a cheap lamp that you don't mind getting stolen too much. It depends on how often it gets stolen, of course, but make the calculations. Always carry a spare.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the included light mount is to affix a complementary pair of strong magnets to the light and to the mount point on your bike. I did this a while back using Sugru and some coin-shaped neodymium magnets bought off Amazon, to let me mount a rear light easily on my helmet. It is so simple to attach that I can do so while riding (with the helmet on), if need be.

You don't need the Sugru necessarily -- any strong thick adhesive should work -- although it is probably the easiest option on handlebars because it stays put so well once you've molded it.

The magnets should be as strong as possible. I have never had the light fall off my helmet unless I actually whacked it while putting my bag on. However, I have seen another light mounted to my bars shift occasionally if I hit a bump.

Magnetic mounts make removing lights as simple as grabbing and pulling, and attaching them an absolute breeze. Holding on would be all that was left to worry about.

Comment: An off the shelf solution for this could be a pair of [Orfos Flare (the original version)](https://www.orfos.us/pages/info), those have magnetics mounts.